# Cocos2d js (Cocos2d x 3.14) on android with deepstream io

Tags: android, cocos2d-js, deepstream.io, cocos2d-x-3.x

Have anyone use cocos2d js with deepstream io ?

I tried to use deepstream client js but it seem to be fail when try to connect server via network (websocket) :

this is adb log:

> 06-06 09:43:19.227: D/cocos2d-x debug info(26288): connectDeepStream
>   [object Object]
>   PlayerActions.login.request@assets/src/modules/Actions/Player.js:22:13,
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.232: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): WebSocket thread start,
>   helper instance: 0x97987760
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.237: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): NOTICE: Initial logging
>   level 911
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.237: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): NOTICE: Libwebsockets
>   version: 2.1.0 james@James-Chen.local-v3.4-139-gbdcf7f8
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.237: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): NOTICE: IPV6 compiled in
>   and enabled
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.237: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): NOTICE: libev support not
>   compiled in
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.237: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): NOTICE: libuv support not
>   compiled in
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.237: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): NOTICE:  Threads: 1 each
>   1024 fds
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.237: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): NOTICE:  mem: platform fd
>   map:  4096 bytes
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.237: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): NOTICE:  Compiled with
>   OpenSSL support
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.247: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): NOTICE:  mem: per-conn:
>   376 bytes + protocol rx buf
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.247: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): protocol: ws, host:
>   ***.***.**.***, port: 3512, path: deepstream
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.247: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): NOTICE: Creating Vhost
>   'default' port -1, 1 protocols, IPv6 on
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.252: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): NOTICE: lws_protocol_init
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.252: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): WebSocket (0xae824ed0)
>   Unhandled websocket event: 32
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.252: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): WebSocket (0xae824ed0)
>   Unhandled websocket event: 29
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.257: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): WebSocket (0xae824ed0)
>   Unhandled websocket event: 24
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.267: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): WebSocket (0xae824ed0)
>   onConnectionError, state: 0 ...
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.267: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): WebSocket (0xae824ed0)
>   onConnectionClosed, state: 2 ...
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.267: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): onConnectionClosed,
>   WebSocket (0xae824ed0) is closing by server.
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.267: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): WebSocket (0xae824ed0)
>   onConnectionClosed DONE!
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.267: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): WebSocket (0xae824ed0)
>   Unhandled websocket event: 45
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.267: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): WebSocket (0xae824ed0)
>   Unhandled websocket event: 33
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.267: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): WebSocket (0xae824ed0)
>   onConnectionClosed, state: 3 ...
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.282: D/cocos2d-x debug info(26288): _onError  [object
>   Object] object
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.282: D/cocos2d-x debug info(26288): [object Object]
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.282: D/cocos2d-x debug info(26288): {"type":"error"}
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.287: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): In the destructor of
>   WebSocket (0xae824ed0)
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.287: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): before join ws thread
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.292: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): NOTICE:
>   lws_context_destroy
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.292: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): WebSocket thread exit,
>   helper instance: 0x97987760
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.292: D/WebSocket.cpp(26288): after join ws thread
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.317: D/cocos2d-x debug info(26288): C connectionError
>   [object Object] string
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.317: D/cocos2d-x debug info(26288): error: string
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.317: D/cocos2d-x debug info(26288): [object Object]
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.317: D/cocos2d-x debug info(26288): connectionError
>
> 06-06 09:43:19.317: D/cocos2d-x debug info(26288): C

i tried to log content of error , but it is only "{"type":"error"}" .

Code is so simple . I only start a deepstream server and try to login to server on android client (js cocos2d-js)

like this :

```
this.client = deepstream(CCDefine.DeepStreamServer).login({username: arg.username, password: arg.password},function(success,data){


cc.log(success,data)

        if(success){
            cc.log('Deep stream connect success')

        }else{
            cc.log('Deep stream connect false')
        }
    })
```

I find out that cocos use libwebsockets without libuv while deepstream use that . can it problem ? I tried to compile libwebsockets with libuv for android but i failed.

Now i currently resolve this problem by use deepstream java SDK , and make a bridge from java to js. 
Thank u all.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the issue is here, but it looks like the WebSocket API could be incompatible. 
Could you try logging the contents of the error object in the deepstream error handler? If you could post a small code sample that would be great too.

Comment: thank for answer, i have resolve it by use deepstream java sdk, and make a bridge from java to js. Thank you